# PCIe x8 format video card (GeForce GT 1030) in x4 open end slot

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I have a motherboard with PCIe x4 open end slot. I would like to know if PCIe x8 video card will work with my motherboard. There is no mechanical problem due to motherboard PCIe x4 slot having open end, so it can accommodate longer PCIe connectors. Additionally, NVidia GT 1030 chip (GP108-3x0-A1) seems to support only 4 PCIe lanes, but for some reason all (most) manufacturers make video cards with PCIe x8 connector. My guess is that the last 4 PCIe channels are inactive (pins 33 to 49). Is that accurate?

Comment: Theoretically for any PC slot/port if you can plug anything in then it is safe to plug but whether this works and gives a enough performance need your try. GPU card is *16(not *8) since nobody will buy a *4 GPU which won't be cheaper than *16 GPU

Answer (score 1):

I have one data point to answer the question: Nvidia GT730 with PCIe 2.0 x8 GPU and full length PCIe x16 connector works fine in a motherboard with open ended PCIe 3.0 x4 slot. I also noticed that GPU can negotiate lower PCIe speed for power saving.